# Error 500 while trying to login to Elder Scrolls Online

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

[image]

I recently bought the game and when I try to login it shows Error 500. It's been days, can anyone please tell me what to do?

Comment: I think you should really post this on their forums, not here.

Comment: Try using a different browser and/or make sure that you don't have any ad blockers, no-script addons, or anything similar active. If that doesn't help, try contacting their support: https://help.elderscrollsonline.com/

Answer (score 2):

An error 500 is an "Internal Server Error", usually this means that there is something wrong with their system. However if this where the case ESO would be down for many people not just you, since I see no evidence of this being the case (no recent reports of any massive outages), the issue is likely on your computer.

I found some trouble shooting for error 500's [here](https://www.lifewire.com/500-internal-server-error-explained-2622938).

To sum up the most important points of what to do.

1: Try restarting your computer and reloading the page.

2: Clear
        your internet cache, and try again.

3: Delete all your cookies, and
        try again.

4: Ensure you don't have any content blockers on
    (adblock, javascript blockers, etc.)

5: Ensure your firewall is set
        to allow connections to the ESO servers.

6: If all else fails,
    contact customer support and have them help you trouble shoot the
    issue.